# MUI: How to handle multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, menu

I'm using MUI to create a navigation menu which has some dropdowns in some of it's links.
This is my code, but each button i click opens the same dropdown menu.

```
function Header() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <StyledHeader>
      <Nav>
        <Link href='/'>
          <Logo color='#fff' width='180' />
        </Link>

        <MenuList>
          {HeaderMenu.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <>
                <MainMenuItem
                  key={i}
                >
                  Button
                    variant='text'
                    color='secondary'
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    endIcon={
                      item.submenu ? (
                        <IconArrowDown width='14' color='#fff' />
                      ) : null
                    }
                  >
                    {item.title}
                  </Button>
                  {item.submenu && (
                    <Menu anchorEl={anchorEl} open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
                      {item?.submenu.map((subItem) => {
                        return (
                          <>
                            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                              {subItem.title}
                            </MenuItem>
                          </>
                        );
                      })}
                    </Menu>
                  )}
                </MainMenuItem>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </MenuList>
      </Nav>
    </StyledHeader>
  );
}
```

How do i reference the dropdown of each button?

Here's a screenshot also:

[image]

Eve though i clicked on "Home", it shows the "About" dropdown, and it shows the same dropdown on whichever menu item i click.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of your issue is this:

```js
  <Menu anchorEl={anchorEl} open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
   ...
  </Menu>
```

It would seem that all submenus have their `open` and `anchorEl` props controlled by the same state. This would mean they are all open or all closed. And anchored to whatever you clicked.

I bet if you inspect it, you have multiple menus displayed on top of each other

Instead of just defining `const open = Boolean(anchorEl)`, which would be true whenever you've clicked a button, perhaps track the title of the menu being opened.

Comment: Yes, you are right. All the dropdowns were open when i inspected and moved the current dropdown to the right a bit. I'm pretty much aware that i have to track the elements by title or id but thats my problem, that i don't know how to do it :)

Comment: The deeper the nesting of your menus, the more complicated it gets.

A fairly simple solution would be to change the open variable to a state: `const [open, setOpen] = useState<string | undefined>()` and then control the state of the menu with `open={open === item.title}`. Your `handleClick` function would need an extra argument: `handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, title: string)` which  would be provided by the Button's `onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, item.title)}`
The `onClose` method then needs to `setOpen(undefined)`

Comment: Yep, working nice! I will accept the answer which leads to this solution. Thanks!